# How to compute $\int_{0}^{1}x\sin (bx) J_0\!\!\left(a\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\!\mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I need a help with integral below,

$$\int_{0}^{1}x\sin (bx) J_0\left(a\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

where $a \geq 0$ and  $b$ are constants and $J_0(x)$ is the **zeroth-order of Bessel function of the first kind.**

**This integral has a closed form solution ?**

I found some integrals similar to the integral above, but I don't have any idea on how to apply it.

I found this integral expression below on Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's book 7th edition, section 6.677, number 6:

$$\int_{0}^{a} \cos (cx)J_0\left(b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx = \frac{\sin (a\sqrt{b^2+c^2})}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}} \quad [b\geq 0]$$

I try use the definition of **zeroth-order of Bessel function of the first kind** to solve this integral:

$$J_0(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(\frac{1}{4}z^2)^k}{(k!)^2}$$

then i found:

$$J_0(a) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{0}^{1}x\sin (bx)\left(1-x^2\right)^k\,\mathrm dx $$

On Wolfram Alpha i found that:

$$\int_{0}^{1}x\sin (bx)\left(1-x^2\right)^k\,\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\pi}a\Gamma (k+1)\tilde{F}_1\Big(;k+\frac{5}{2};-\frac{a^2}{4}\Big)$$

where $\tilde{F}_1$ is the **Regularized Hypergeometric Function**, where:

$$\tilde{F}_1\Big(;k+\frac{5}{2};-\frac{a^2}{4}\Big) =  \frac{J_{k+\frac{3}{2}}(a) }{(\frac{a}{2})^{k+\frac{3}{2}}}$$

therefore:

$$\int_{0}^{1}x\sin (bx) J_0\left(a\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx = J_0(a)\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\pi}a \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Gamma (k+1) J_{k+\frac{3}{2}}(a)\Big(\frac{a}{2}\Big)^{-(k+\frac{3}{2})} $$

**The solution found above is right ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want..." ?  What's stopping you from doing so? Please ask a question.

Comment: Why do you believe this integral has a closed form?

Comment: What is  bessel function of first kind and zero order?

Comment: "What's stopping you from doing so? Please ask a question." - Sorry, this is my first post, the question is "This integral can be solved in closed form  ?"

Comment: "Why do you believe this integral has a closed form?" I don´t have indications, i prefer to be in closed form, but an approximation it is fine for me too

Comment: "What is bessel function of first kind and zero order? " - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html is the function of this link, but with zero order

Comment: Haveyou tried to differentiate the integral from Gradshteyn?

Comment: @tired, I don´t, but also i don´t know how can i do that, can you give me a hint to start this process ?

Comment: @BrunoFelipe see the answer by Marius Iwaniuk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggestion by user [tired](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/101233/tired):

Integral expression below on Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's book 7th edition, section 6.677, number 6:

$$\int_0^1 \cos (b x) J_0\left(a \sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \, dx=\frac{\sin
   \left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Differentiate  for variable `b`:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\partial \left(\cos (b x) J_0\left(a \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right)}{\partial b} \,
   dx=\frac{\partial }{\partial b}\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 x \sin (b x) J_0\left(a \sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \, dx=-\frac{b \cos
   \left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{b \sin \left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^{3/2}}}$$

Comment: Thank you!, i am very grateful

Comment: @BrunoFelipe. You are welcome.

Comment: To [tired, Mariusz Iwaniuk] Sir, I am dealing with the similar integration $\int_0^1 \sin{bx} J_0(\sqrt{1-x^2})\, dx$..No result of this integral mentioned in  Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's book 7th edition, section 6.677. Is the result will be zero.Would you kindly tell me what will be the closed form result of this integration or the methods how I can proceed to solve it.

Comment: @R.Bhattacharya. Write a new question.

Comment: Okay Sir...I shall post the link (of the new question) here for your perusal...

Comment: To [tired, Mariusz Iwaniuk] Sir, Kindly peruse the link here: - \cite{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637721/integration-related-to-bessel-function}, where I have posted the new question as you told and the  integration $\int_0^1\sin (bx) J_0(a\sqrt{1−x^2})\,dx$ arises in $I_1$.Would you kindly suggest me what to do to get a closed form result.