# Integration related to Bessel function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, fourier-transform, complex-integration

Sir,

While studying on the convolution theorem using Green's function *(using weyl identity)* and doing some problems related to this, I have faced the following integration and I want to find out the closed form answer:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp{isk\Big[\sqrt{1-p^2-q^2}\Big]}}{\sqrt{1-p^2-q^2}}\exp{-ik(px+qy)}\,dp\,dq$$
Where, $s \in \mathbb R(+)$, $k$ and $\beta \in \mathbb R(+)$ are constants.

After searching some texts related to *Weyl identity and Sommerfeld identity*, what I did is as follows:

I took $k_r^2= k^2(p^2+q^2)$; where $kp=k_r \cos \phi$ and $kq=k_r \sin \phi$.
Therefore, the above integral becomes,
$$I=\frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\exp{is\sqrt{k^2-k_r^2}}}{\sqrt{k^2-k_r^2}}\exp{ik_r(x\cos \phi+y\sin \phi)} \times k_r \, dk_r \,d\phi$$
After doing the $\phi$ integral first it gives,
$$I=\frac{2\pi}{k^2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\exp{is\sqrt{k^2-k_r^2}}}{\sqrt{k^2-k_r^2}} J_0(k_r\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) k_r \, dk_r$$
Now two cases will arise here **1)** when **$k^2>k_r^2$** and 
**2)** when **$k_r^2\geq k^2$ i.e. $\sqrt{k^2-k_r^2}=i\sqrt{k_r^2-k^2}$**
Accordingly, I can write, $$I=I_1+I_2$$,
Where, $$I_1=\lim{a\rightarrow k}\int_0^a\frac{\exp{is\sqrt{k^2-k_r^2}}}{\sqrt{k^2-k_r^2}} J_0(k_rR) k_r \, dk_r$$ where, $R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$and 
$$I_2=\int_k^{\infty}\frac{\exp{-s\sqrt{k_r^2-k^2}}}{\sqrt{k_r^2-k^2}} J_0(k_rR) k_r \, dk_r$$
Now, if I consider the further substitution i.e. for $I_1$, such that $k^2-k_r^2=w^2$, then, it becomes,
$$I_1=\int_0^k\exp{i(sw)} J_0(\sqrt{k^2-w^2}R) \, dw$$
and similarly, taking substitution, $k_r^2-k^2=w^2$,
$$I_2=\int_k^{\infty}\exp{(-sw)} J_0(\sqrt{k^2+w^2}R) \, dw$$
Would you kindly check the procedure I did and then suggest me what to do further or give me any relevant references such that I can get the closed form answer of this integral.

Thanking you..

Comment: In case (1), the limits of the $p$ integral are $-\infty$ to $\infty$, which means $p^2+q^2 < 1$ definitely won't be satisfied over the whole domain of integration.

Comment: Sure Sir, then, the limit may be broken from $-\infty$ to $a$ and then $a$ to $\infty$, where, $a^2= 1-q^2$ and in the later case $\sqrt{a^2-p^2}=i\sqrt{p^2-a^2}$, we get the case 2. Sir, is my assumption  correct?

Comment: ( To eyeballfrog) Sir, the question is edited considering the valuable comment, you posted in this regard. Would you please give any further suggestion.